# Azure IoT Edge iotedge check shows Address not available var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock

Tags: azure, ubuntu-18.04, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

When I run iotedge check I see this error
config.yaml has correct URIs for daemon mgmt endpoint - Error
One or more errors occurred. (Address not available var/run/iotedge/mgmt.sock)

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of iotedge are you running? There is a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/3829) that this might be related to (and has a fix according to that link).

Comment: iotedge/bionic,now 1.0.10.1-1 amd64 [installed]

Comment: That patch doesn't appear to have resolved the issue on Ubuntu 18/Linux

Comment: Should be [fixed](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/pull/3950) in 1.0.10.2, which was released just a few days ago.

Comment: .2 doesn't appear to be available yet via 
sudo apt-get install iotedge=1.0.10.2

Comment: I see it on my Ubuntu 18.04 VM.
    $ apt-cache madison iotedge
    iotedge | 1.0.10.2-1 | https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/multiarch/prod bionic/main amd64 Packages
    ...

Comment: I just upgraded to 20.04 and tried apt-get install iotedge=1.0.10.2 and apt-get install iotedge=1.0.10.2-1 and both say version not found.  Should I be installing it another way?

Comment: Did you install the packages.microsoft.com repository config first? BTW I don't think we have an Ubuntu 20.04 package repository, although maybe the 18.04 repo would work. Instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge?view=iotedge-2018-06&tabs=linux).

Comment: These are the same instructions I used when on 18.04 and 20.04.  On 20.04, I just changed the version in the curl url to https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04 and it worked. Either way I get the version not found.

Comment: I re-ran this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-update-iot-edge?view=iotedge-2018-06 process and I now see 10.2 available .  I will try to install it next.

Comment: All good now!  Thanks @DamonBarry

Answer (score -1):

Damon's solution in comments above solved the problem. The patch fix error.